# Getting networks... "Deploy Wordpress" greyed out

Tags: wordpress, deployment, google-compute-engine

I am unable to deploy a Wordpress Instance, with multiple refreshes and attempts in different browsers I am unable to "get networks".

Please see the screenshot of the greyed out "Deploy Wordpress" button and the fact that all fields are completed.

[image: Getting networks]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug I've been tracking personally to see how often it occurs.  Typically the network list is resolved in 30 seconds or so and the button will then be enabled.  I haven't seen latencies any longer than that.  Can you try again and see if it works?